# Save the coordinates of my canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am pretty new at this, but i’ve created a canvas where its possible to draw with both mouse and touch, and when I am finished with the drawing I want to save the coordinates of the drawing to a simple txt file(Not save as image).Is there anybody how knows if it possible and how to do it?

And is there a way to save the coordinates automatically when the mouseEnd or touchEnd event is fired(I don’t want to use a save button if possible)?

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events (And their coordinates), and store this data in some format.
You can't however, save a txt file from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

**Put each coordinate from mousedown and mousemove events into a javascript object:**

```
{ x:10, y:25 }
```

**And put all your coordinate-objects in an array:**

```
var coordinates=[

{ x:10, y:25 },

{ x:20, y:70 },

];
```

**When done painting: use JSON.stringify to turn your coordinates array into text that can be stored in a text file:**

```
var coordinateText = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
```